# How is Landsat NDWI calculated in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, normalized-difference-water-index

I am using Google Earth Engine to compute NDWI time series, in particular by plotting "Landsat 7 Collection 1 Tier 1 8-Day NDWI Composite" data values

The product description says:
These Landsat 7 Collection 1 Tier 1 composites are made from Tier 1 orthorectified scenes, using the computed top-of-atmosphere (TOA) reflectance.
It is derived from the Near-IR band and a second IR band, ≈1.24μm when available and the nearest available IR band otherwise.

This seems strange to me, since Landsat 7 has no 1.24μm band, but only a SWIR band at 1.55-1.75 μm
https://landsat.usgs.gov/what-are-band-designations-landsat-satellites

How does the Google algorithm calculates it?

Answer (score 2):

It is computed as (NIr1 - NIr2) / (NIr1 + NIr2).  For ETM+, NIr1 is B4 and NIr2 is B5.  Note that this is the [Gao (1996)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425796000673) version of NDWI (which may or may not be suitable for Landsat) and should not be confused with the [McFeeters (1996)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01431169608948714) NDWI.

Comment: This confirms my guess. But it is not Gao Version. Gao used  0.86-μm and the 1.24-μm wavelenght, but considering ETM+ the computation occurs with 0.85 and 1.65. It should be labeled as NDII - Normalized Difference Infrared Index. See here for more info:https://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci.net/20/3361/2016/